# Extract various information

Tags: python, csv

**Overview**

would like to extract various information like name, date and address from a 2 column csv file before writing to another csv file

**Conditions**

1. Extract **Name** by first row as it will always be the first
   row.
2. Extract **Date** by regex (is there regex in python?) ##/##/####
       format
3. Extract **Address** by the constant keyword 'road'

---

**Example CSV dummy Source data reference file format viewed from EXCEL**

---

```
       ID,DATA
     88888,DADDY            
     88888,2/06/2016        
     88888,new issac road        
     99999,MUMMY            
     99999,samsung road   
     99999,12/02/2016
```

**Desired CSV outcome**

```
ID,Name,Address,DATE
8888,DADDY,new issac road,2/06/2016 
9999,MUMMY,samsung road,12/02/2016
```

**What i have so far:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('dummy_data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k
uniqueidstatement = columns['receipt_id']

print uniqueidstatement

resultFile = open("wtf.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
wr.writerow(uniqueidstatement)
```

Comment: what's the actual problem you are having?

Comment: A while loop would be idea right?

Comment: I have no idea where to start based on those conditions that i have stated

Comment: well, what does your code output now and how is it different to what you want?

Comment: my output now is 88888| 22222| 55555| 55555 | 77777 etc

Comment: I cannot see how your expected output comes about, how do you get `9999     DADDY` and  `8888       MUMMY`? They are the reverse in your file

Comment: Also what about the date?

Comment: I don't understand from where you get the value 'receipt_id' to use as a key ? Anyway, there is regex in Python : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: sorry i have edited already

Comment: receipt_id' is basically ID

Comment: Beside, I don't think we can consider the input format you gave to be CSV (or any *SV…). If there is a blank line between each record you could start splitting on this to loop through each record.

Comment: Is your data comma delimited or what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the sections by `ID` and from each group you can determine which is the date and which is the address with some simple logic .

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open("test.csv") as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(["ID","NAME","ADDRESS", "DATE"])
    groups = groupby(csv.reader(f), key=itemgetter(0))
    for k, v in groups:
        id_, name = next(v)
        add_date_1, add_date_2 = next(v)[1], next(v)[1]
        date, add = (add_date_1, add_date_2) if "road" in add_date_2 else  (add_date_2, add_date_1)
        writer.writerow([id_, name, add, date])
```

Comment: I gotten ID,NAME,ADDRESS,DATE followed by blank row and 88888 DADDY new issac road 2/06/2016 (no comma is good) thats all. I kinda lost where did the rest went

Comment: `id_, name, _ = next(v)` >>>>>> REFER to id_ of the source csv file column while name refer to source csv file name column? i deleted the ,_

Comment: Is your data separated by blank lines and delimiter by commas? Also those comments are actually there or not?

Comment: comments are not there! my data searated by commas when viewed in text file whereas it is not seen in MS excel (line by line)

Comment: So tab  delimited? Post a sample of the content *exactly* as it appears in your file including delimiters.

Comment: `id,name
88888,DADDY
88888,3/6/2016
88888,new issac road
99999,MUMMU
99999,5/5/1992
99999,abbey road
77777,ynnne
77777,8/8/2016
77777,yessy road
`   - cant format exactly what i wanted. This is copied from text editor

Comment: Add it to your question as I have no idea what is what.

Comment: @Perlinn, I have added what the code produces using your input file. If that does not work then your format is somewhat different to what you have provided.

Comment: sorry to trouble you sir! My CSV do not have blank space between each unique ID. I just realized it.... no wonder it only returned one input... sorry! I know it has to do with the next syntax. How do i get ride of it?

Comment: Thank you so much! You are so gracious, sweet and handsome too! :D Kiss  for you!